# Rar file extract is failed

Tags: rar

I'm trying to extract a rar file is first time  is opened then its closed and to reopen the file is failed." an error occured while loading the archive manager" this alert message displayed

Comment: Are you sure that the file is complete? If you downloaded it, check its size to see if it is right.

Comment: ya sure its complete....im opened it ... once again i wanna to open this file  error comes

Answer (score 74):

Install **unrar** to open and extract rar archives.

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
2. Run

   ```
   sudo apt install unrar
   ```

Now file-roller should open and extract rar archives without error.

If you cannot install unrar, you need to activate the multiverse repository; but, I assume you have them activated as they are by default.

Comment: I can confirm, this works in all _buntu distros and Linux Mint

Comment: Worked for me in 16.04

Comment: Nice. Works on Ubuntu 18.04 aswell

Comment: I got the same error when extracting files from split Rar files. this resolved the issue.

Comment: Ubuntu `20.04.4 LTS`  Gnome `3.36.8` works great.  You may have to close/re-open file explorer.   I did not have to log out and log back in or reboot my computer.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me

Comment: Still working. I had to reboot to get it to work, but as mentioned above close/re-opening file explorer may be enough.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this happened to me when a file was parted in some files, and I tried this from the command line:

```
unrar e "archive.part1.rar"
```

Comment: You should elaborate your answer a little more. This answer it's quite vague...

Comment: Do you mean "*when a file is split into [multivolume archives](https://www.win-rar.com/split-files-archive.html?&L=0)*"? Please [edit] your answer and clarify.

Comment: e flag specifies extract to current directory which is unnecessary if you don't specify an output directory. x flag retains the archive directory structure, which is the default in the GUI and usually preferred: unrar x archivename

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem fixed by installing b1freearchiver:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget b1.org/smart-download/0/os=deb64/b1freearchiver_current_stable_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi b1freearchiver_current_stable_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

good suggestions above.  However, what I found is that when I did a `cd` to the directory with the terminal it showed that it was a 'string' instead of a normal file.  Then I tested something quick and it worked perfectly: I just deleted the empty space between the words in the filename, and right click 'extract' again and it extracted perfectly.  So the solution might be that simple for you too, if you have a blank space in the file name. Example:

`FILE NAME.rar` change to -> `FILE_NAME.rar`

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you have a blank space in the filename you can also put the filename  between single quotes and it also works. No renaming needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to use `unrar`. The benefit is that this version will keep the folder structure of the original `.rar` file.

```
unrar x -ad "archive.rar"
```